# Ckeditor content retrieval using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, forms, ckeditor, submit

I've been trying to integrate ckeditor in my php website, and I've encountered the following issue.

Essentially, the content in ckeditor wouldn't appear in the $_POST variable after submitting the form.

I looked the issue up and apparently one has to update the form field with a small piece of code.

So I wrote the corresponding script and linked it to the submit button in order to get the result I want, but $_POST still shows up as empty.

I'm inexperienced with Javascript so the error probably lies there. Any ideas?

cktest.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
        <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor</title>
        <!-- Make sure the path to CKEditor is correct. -->
        <script src="http://localhost/ECLIPSEPHP/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action = <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
        ?>>
            <textarea name="test" id="test" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
            <input type = "submit" name = 'submitButton' id = 'submitButton' value = 'Submit'>
            <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="test"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'test' );
            </script>
            <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://localhost/ECLIPSEPHP/js/update.js"></script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
//echo $_POST['test'];
    ?>
```

The javascript supposed to handle the onclick event :

```
function updateAllMessageForms()
{
    for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }
}

var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
submitButton.onclick = updateAllMessageForms;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a lot of problems with that code. The first thing to check is to add a method to that form tag: `method="post"`.

See what `<form action = <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>>` renders. It looks like it could be a wrong. I'm guessing it should be more like `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">`.

Don't use `'` for HTML attribute delimiters, use `"` instead: `'submitButton'` --> `"submitButton"`.

If you edit the updateElement a little: `CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement(); alert(1);` - do you see the alert? If not, that code is not being called and you need to edit it so that it is.

Don't add spaces between your attribute name, the equals symbol and the value. That looks very strange and could be interpreted wrong or it could send Internet Explorer into quirks mode. Try to change this style: `type = "submit"` to `type="submit"` and keep up with that style.

Remember that it's often a good idea to look at the Rendered source in the browser to see what the browser actually gets. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply and the tips about bad practice. I've made the changes you indicated.

I changed the onclick to onsubmit. In that case, I wouldn't get the alert if I put it inside the function, only if it is outside of it. However, changing it back to onclick meant the alert was also triggered inside the function.

This seems rather strange, but however it does indicate that the script is triggered. Do you have a better idea of what my problem might be ?

Comment: Hmm, could you paste your current code for example to http://pastebin.com/ ? I could have a look at it there. My imagination is not good enough to imagine without having a look at the code :).

Comment: Here's the js :

[link](http://pastebin.com/e0jx3CU1)

and the php :
[link](http://pastebin.com/ykZmzGE4)

Comment: Have a look at this and try it out: http://pastebin.com/TPU7R46J - I added the `method` attribute to the form tag. I also moved the JavaScript to inline - it doesn't matter, but it's easier to manage just 1 file when testing in my opinion. I also moved the function call to `updateAllMessageForms()` so that it's in the `onsubmit` attribute of the form, not tied to the button element. How about that`

Comment: If you don't see an alert when submitting that form, something is really wrong and/or I fail at JavaScript.  Notice that I added one `input` element to the form. This way, you can always see that at least something is being posted with the form :)

Comment: Ehh, it was just the 'post' thing that solved it... I really am an idiot...

I now get an array which contains a string with html tags. Thanks a lot for your help, and sorry for the really stupid error in my code.

Comment: No worries, things like that are really easy to miss - I've missed more obvious problems many times!

Comment: Actually, there's more to it. I'm having trouble replacing textareas with ckeditor in forms which were already there. Although I use the same code, $_POST returns nothing for the ckeditor part of such forms. I've included the code in the edit.

Comment: Never mind, i'll look more into it before posting, it's a lot of code at once. On a side note, strangely enough, if I have no css whatsoever, ckeditor doesn't show up.