# Ckeditor data not retrieved for some form (php)

Tags: php, html, forms, post, ckeditor

I made a post here a couple of days ago :

[Ckeditor content retrieval using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699801/ckeditor-content-retrieval-using-php)

(I hope this is ok, by the way, asking a related question in a new thread, but it seemed awkward to stay on the same thread).

It's now working fine. However, when replacing textareas by ckeditor in other forms, the data isn't retrieved although the code is very similar.

I think I might be limited by my understading of php forms for this problem. Anyway, here's the code :

```
<section id="mainsection">
    <script src="http://localhost/Project/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>               
    <h1> ADD INDIVIDUAL </h1>                   

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?> method="post">
        <p>
            <label for="fullname">Full Name</label> : <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" /><br />
            <label for="description">Biography</label> :  <input type="textarea" name="description" id="description" /><br />   
            <label for="file">Find image</label> :  <input name="personimage" type="file" id="personimage" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
       </p>
       <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' );
       </script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/Project/js/update.js"></script>
    </form> 

<?php
    var_dump($_POST);

       /* if(isset($_POST['fullname']) AND isset($_POST['description']))
        {
            $post = array('fullname' => $_POST["fullname"],
            'description' => $_POST["description"],
            );  
            add_person($post);      
        }else{  
            echo 'Not every parameter has been set';
        }*/
?>
```

The code works fine without ckeditor. But the present code doesn't add the ckeditor content to $_POST, which confuses me as it doesn't seem to be fundamentally different to the code in the link I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### There are some validation errors which should be fixed

---

So firstly, `action`'s value `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>` should be closed with quotes (`""`), but there is no need to fill this attribute with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. You may let this attribute empty.

After that, you should use `<textarea></textarea>` format what is more valid than `<input type="textarea" />` as you can see in [W3 Input reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.html) there is no `input type=textarea` option. So it should be

```
<textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
```

Instead of

```
<input type="textarea" name="description" id="description" />
```

The final result should looks like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="fullname">Full Name</label> : <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" /><br />
        <label for="description">Biography</label> :  <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea><br />   
        <label for="file">Find image</label> :  <input name="personimage" type="file" id="personimage" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
   </p>
   <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' );
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/Project/js/update.js"></script>
</form>
```

After these changes, try `var_dump($_POST);` again.

Comment: Holy macaroni

That's solved my problem. I'm amazed neither I nor my debugger picked that one up. Sorry about thhat

Comment: Hi @spliblib if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/232820) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.